# Yesod - Include a base widget only once

Tags: haskell, widget, handler, yesod, flags

I have a `Widget` `a_i` that relies on a base `Widget` `b`. `b` contains Javascript that `a` requires to work.

Currently, the widgets are included on a page like so:

```
getHomeR = defaultLayout $ do
  b
  a_1
  a_2
```

I want to automatically include `b` if `a_i` is used but only do this once for any particular handler run.

`Widget` appears to use `IO` underneath - can I use this to set some kind of flag which allow `b` only to be included once? Is there already functionality to set some kind of flag that is exclusive to a single handler thread?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the purpose of widget, to allow to insert javascript only once. Your use case seemt to correspond to the described [there](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2013/01/adding-css-js). You should use `addScript` in `a` and it should be only added once.